# Spring consumers not getting reconnected to rabbit mq queue once connection failed

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a  one producer, two consumer setup using rabbitMQ as broker and producers/consumers applications configured in spring(config as mentioned below). I am facing an issue of reconnecting to consumers when ever there is a failure in consumer machine,the consumer application is usually recovering in some time but the connection between broker(Queue) and consumer is not being reestablished,

I'verified in rabbit-MQ admin console, and I found no consumers are listed under queue though the consumers has recovered automatically after some time.

Any insight on how to resolve this is appreciated, Please let me know if any further details are needed.

Connection Factory config is as below

```
@Bean 
public CachingConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() throws Exception 
{
    com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory factory = new com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory(); 
    factory.setHost(host);
    factory.setUsername(username); 
    factory.setPassword(password);
    factory.setPort(5671);
    factory.useSslProtocol(); 
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(factory);
    return connectionFactory; 
}
```

---

Sample container factories

```
   @Bean(name = "stockcontainer") 
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleStokcontainer()  throws Exception
    {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
        factory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(2); 
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(4);
        factory.setPrefetchCount(20);
        return factory; 
    }
    
    
    @Bean(name = "StockUploadSimplecontainer") 
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory StockUploadListenerContainerFactory()  throws Exception
    {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
        factory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(2); 
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(4);
        factory.setPrefetchCount(15);
        return factory;
    }
```

---

One of Listeners in consumer

```
@RabbitListener( queues = "${stock_daily.sync.queue}", containerFactory = "stockcontainer", autoStartup = "true")
    public void stockDailySync(SftpStockDailySyncAsyncRequest sftpStockDailySyncRequest) {
        
    }
```

---

exception

> 2021-07-20 18:05:08.081  INFO 15087 --- [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-7]
> o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer: Restarting
> Consumer@1e89e61:
> tags=[{amq.ctag-jOkLesmTRAMxV1U6P6RTIg=omnirio_supplierbulk_queue}],
> channel=Cached Rabbit Channel:
> AMQChannel(amqp://prod-core-mq@**.*.*.*:5671/,11), conn:
> Proxy@4de7441e Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@302dbb33
> [delegate=amqp://prod-core-mq@**.*.*.*:5671/, localPort= 36542],
> acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0 2021-07-20 18:05:08.081 ERROR
> 15087 --- [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-8]
> o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer: Failed to check/redeclare
> auto-delete queue(s).
>
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AutoRecoverConnectionNotCurrentlyOpenException:
> Auto recovery connection is not currently open
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.isOpen(SimpleConnection.java:100)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.isOpen(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1240)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:472)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.access$1500(CachingConnectionFactory.java:94)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1161)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1803)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1771)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1752)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:338)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1604)
> [spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963)
> [spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_292]
>
> 2021-07-20 18:05:08.806  INFO 15087 --- [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-6]
> o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer: Restarting
> Consumer@664b6f7c:
> tags=[{amq.ctag-HzahvRL3wv6m0E4BKPaROw=omnirio_supplierbulk_queue}],
> channel=Cached Rabbit Channel:
> AMQChannel(amqp://prod-core-mq@**.*.*.*:5671/,4), conn: Proxy@4de7441e
> Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@302dbb33
> [delegate=amqp://prod-core-mq@**.*.*.*:5671/, localPort= 36542],
> acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0 2021-07-20 18:05:08.807 ERROR
> 15087 --- [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9]
> o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer: Failed to check/redeclare
> auto-delete queue(s).
>
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AutoRecoverConnectionNotCurrentlyOpenException:
> Auto recovery connection is not currently open
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.isOpen(SimpleConnection.java:100)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.isOpen(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1240)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:472)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.access$1500(CachingConnectionFactory.java:94)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1161)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1803)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1771)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1752)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:338)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1604)
> [spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963)
> [spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_292]

---

I have updated the rabbitConnectionFactory() method by adding a statement "factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(false) ", now the factory method is as shown below, this time I have encountered a different exception mentioned below(Exception-2)

```
@Bean 
    public CachingConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() throws Exception 
    {
        com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory factory = new com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory(); 
        factory.setHost(host);
        factory.setUsername(username); 
        factory.setPassword(password);
        factory.setPort(5671);
        factory.useSslProtocol(); 
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(factory);
        return connectionFactory; 
    }
```

***Exception -2***

> org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException:
> com.rabbitmq.client.ChannelContinuationTimeoutException: Continuation
> call for method #method<channel.open>(out-of-band=) on channel
> AMQChannel(amqp://prod-core-mq@*:5671/,22) (#22) timed out
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:71)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.createChannel(SimpleConnection.java:68)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1156)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.access$200(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1144)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.doCreateBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:585)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:568)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getCachedChannelProxy(CachingConnectionFactory.java:538)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:520)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.access$1500(CachingConnectionFactory.java:94)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1161)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1803)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1771)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1752)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:338)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1604)
> [spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963)
> [spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_292] Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ChannelContinuationTimeoutException:
> Continuation call for method #method<channel.open>(out-of-band=) on
> channel AMQChannel(amqp://prod-core-mq@*:5671/,22) (#22) timed out
> at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrapTimeoutException(AMQChannel.java:308)
> ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
> at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:290)
> ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
> at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:138)
> ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
> at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.open(ChannelN.java:133) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
> at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelManager.createChannel(ChannelManager.java:176)
> ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
> at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.createChannel(AMQConnection.java:542)
> ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
> at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.createChannel(AutorecoveringConnection.java:108)
> ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.createChannel(SimpleConnection.java:57)
> ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
> ... 15 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
> at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:77) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
> at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:120)
> ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
> at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
> ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
> at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:494)
> ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
> at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:288)
> ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
> at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:138)
> ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
> at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.open(ChannelN.java:133) ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
> at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelManager.createChannel(ChannelManager.java:176)
> ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
> at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.createChannel(AMQConnection.java:542)
> ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
> at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.createChannel(AutorecoveringConnection.java:108)
> ~[amqp-client-5.1.2.jar!/:5.1.2]
> at org.springframework.amqp.r

Comment: You need to show logs.

Comment: @GaryRussell i have edited my question by including the logs

Answer (score 0):

> AutoRecoverConnectionNotCurrentlyOpenException

Don't use `autoRecoveryEnabled` with Spring AMQP - it is not compatible (Spring has had its own recovery mechanism long before auto recovery was added to the amqp-client); it is effectively disabled anyway - Spring closes any automatically recovered connections.

That error is transient; when the connection is recovered by the client, Spring will close it and a new connection will be created.

> 2.0.3.RELEASE

2.0.x is no longer supported; you should upgrade to 2.2.18 or 2.3.10 as soon as possible.

Comment: as suggested i have updated the factory method with "factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(false);"  statement and restarted the application, But after some time i have got a different exception from consumer , can you shed some light on that as well. I have edited my question with new exception<exception-2>

Comment: `>ChannelContinuationTimeoutException` I don't know what can cause that - seems odd - the default timeout is 10 minutes!! I suggest you look in the broker logs for clues and/or ask the RabbitMQ guys on the `rabbitmq-users` Google Group what could be causing that.